# Firebase Database or Cloud SQL?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-sql

I am creating a small service for clients booking technicians live. I'm old-school and am used to a SQL-database and Python solving things as I always have done.

My goal (I think) is to create a small backend in Python with Flask and SQLAlchemy and using the Restless package to Flask and storing everything in Cloud SQL.

But now I see Firebase Database and I wonder if that is a better way for me to go? I'm not an experienced developer but an old grumpy sysadmin used to Linux.

I am not used to NoSQL but perhaps I should just relearn, even if it delays my project? Or can I combine it in some way to simplify the development for me?

Whatever happens I would prefer to stay with Python (3.5)

Sorry for all the questions, but I am new to this :)

Comment: Have you considered using Sqlite?

Comment: Frankly, I suggest (also "old school" ...) that you choose a solution that *works,* so that your *clients* can efficiently "book their technicians." **That** is what's going to bring you *r-e-v-e-n-u-e.*  As the old-school Perl folks still say:  **TMTOWTDI** = *There's More Than One Way To Do It.* The corollary to that maxim is The Nike Principle: "just *do* it." (I'll omit the "Cable Guy's" way of saying it ...) **;-)**

Comment: I could go any way, perhaps I should just go with what I know (or well, know a bit about) in this case SQL. I am mostly looking for the whole "relatime" bit. Currently I am creating schemas and I hope I don't screw it up :)

Comment: Sqlite or MySQL doesn't matter right now. Currently I use Sqlite when I develop on my laptop, but I prefer CloudSQL for production.